# AWS Glue pushdown predicate not working properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm trying to optimize my Glue/PySpark job by using push down predicates.

```
start = date(2019, 2, 13) 
end = date(2019, 2, 27) 
print(">>> Generate data frame for ", start, " to ", end, "... ")
relaventDatesDf = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(start=start, stop=end)
])
relaventDatesDf.createOrReplaceTempView("relaventDates")

relaventDatesDf = spark.sql("SELECT explode(generate_date_series(start, stop)) AS querydatetime FROM relaventDates")
relaventDatesDf.createOrReplaceTempView("relaventDates")
print("===LOG:Dates===")
relaventDatesDf.show()

flightsGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "xxx", table_name = "flights", transformation_ctx="flights", push_down_predicate="""
    querydatetime BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'
    AND querydestinationplace IN (%s)
""" % (start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), ",".join(map(lambda s: str(s), arr))))
```

However it appears, that Glue still attempts to read data outside the specified date range?

```
INFO S3NativeFileSystem: Opening 's3://.../flights/querydestinationplace=12191/querydatetime=2019-03-01/part-00045-6cdebbb1-562c-43fa-915d-93b125aeee61.c000.snappy.parquet' for reading
INFO FileScanRDD: Reading File path: s3://.../flights/querydestinationplace=12191/querydatetime=2019-03-10/part-00021-34a13146-8fb2-43de-9df2-d8925cbe472d.c000.snappy.parquet, range: 0-11797922, partition values: [12191,17965]
WARN S3AbortableInputStream: Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.
INFO S3NativeFileSystem: Opening 's3://.../flights/querydestinationplace=12191/querydatetime=2019-03-10/part-00021-34a13146-8fb2-43de-9df2-d8925cbe472d.c000.snappy.parquet' for reading
WARN S3AbortableInputStream: Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.
```

Notice the `querydatetime=2019-03-01` and `querydatetime=2019-03-10` its outside the specified range of `2019-02-13 - 2019-02-27`. Is that why there's the next line "aborting HTTP connection" tho? It goes on to say "This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior" is something wrong?

I wonder if the problem is because it does not support BETWEEN inside the predicate or IN?

---

The table create DDL

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `flights`(
  `id` string, 
  `querytaskid` string, 
  `queryoriginplace` string, 
  `queryoutbounddate` string, 
  `queryinbounddate` string, 
  `querycabinclass` string, 
  `querycurrency` string, 
  `agent` string, 
  `quoteageinminutes` string, 
  `price` string, 
  `outboundlegid` string, 
  `inboundlegid` string, 
  `outdeparture` string, 
  `outarrival` string, 
  `outduration` string, 
  `outjourneymode` string, 
  `outstops` string, 
  `outcarriers` string, 
  `outoperatingcarriers` string, 
  `numberoutstops` string, 
  `numberoutcarriers` string, 
  `numberoutoperatingcarriers` string, 
  `indeparture` string, 
  `inarrival` string, 
  `induration` string, 
  `injourneymode` string, 
  `instops` string, 
  `incarriers` string, 
  `inoperatingcarriers` string, 
  `numberinstops` string, 
  `numberincarriers` string, 
  `numberinoperatingcarriers` string)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `querydestinationplace` string, 
  `querydatetime` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://pinfare-glue/flights/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER'='pinfare-parquet', 
  'averageRecordSize'='19', 
  'classification'='parquet', 
  'compressionType'='none', 
  'objectCount'='623609', 
  'recordCount'='4368434222', 
  'sizeKey'='86509997099', 
  'typeOfData'='file')
```

Comment: Are the partitions defined correctly in the table definition in Glue's catalog?
Can you share the table's `PARTITIONED BY` clause?

Comment: @ya2410 updated post with table DDL

Comment: One of the issue I can see with the code is that you are using "today" instead of "end" in the between clause. Though I don't see the today variable declared anywhere in your code, I am assuming it has been initialized with today's date. In that case the range will be different and the partitions being read by glue spark is correct.

Comment: @HarshBafna oh ... you are correct, theres my mistake there, its likely causing more data to be read ... thus a unexpectedly long processing time! Thank you

Comment: @JiewMeng Did it help you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

One of the issue I can see with the code is that you are using "today" instead of "end" in the between clause. Though I don't see the today variable declared anywhere in your code, I am assuming it has been initialized with today's date.

In that case the range will be different and the partitions being read by glue spark is correct.

Answer (score 3):

In order to push down your condition, you need to change the order of columns in your partition by clause of table definition

A condition having  "in" predicate on first partition column can not be push down as you are expecting.

Let me if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Pushdown predicates in Glue DynamicFrame works fine with **between** as well as **IN** clause.

As long as you have correct sequence of partition columns defined in table definition and in query.

I have table with three level of partitions.

```
s3://bucket/flights/year=2018/month=01/day=01 -> 50 records
s3://bucket/flights/year=2018/month=02/day=02 -> 40 records
s3://bucket/flights/year=2018/month=03/day=03 -> 30 records
```

Read data in dynamicFrame

```
ds = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database = "abc",table_name = "pqr", transformation_ctx = "flights",
    push_down_predicate = "(year == '2018' and month between '02' and '03' and day in ('03'))"
    )
ds.count()
```

Output:

```
30 records
```

So, you are gonna get the correct results, if sequence of columns is correctly specified. Also note, you need to specify '(quote) **`IN('%s')`** in IN clause.

Partition columns in table:

```
querydestinationplace string, 
querydatetime string
```

Data read in DynamicFrame:

```
flightsGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "xxx", table_name = "flights", transformation_ctx="flights", 
    push_down_predicate=
    """querydestinationplace IN ('%s') AND 
       querydatetime BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s' 
    """ 
    % 
    ( ",".join(map(lambda s: str(s), arr)), 
        start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the end as this

```
start = str(date(2019, 2, 13))
end = str(date(2019, 2, 27)) 
# Set your push_down_predicate variable

pd_predicate = "querydatetime >= '" + start + "' and querydatetime < '" + end + "'"
#pd_predicate = "querydatetime between '" + start + "' AND '" + end + "'" # Or this one?

flightsGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database = "xxx"
    , table_name = "flights"
    , transformation_ctx="flights"
    , push_down_predicate=pd_predicate)
```

The `pd_predicate` will be a string that will work as a push_down_predicate.

Here is a nice read about it if you like.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/work-with-partitioned-data-in-aws-glue/

Comment: So do I interprete it as BETWEEN does not work well inside a pushdown predicate?